# Angular UI Router: ui-sref does not render render the page I'm trying to route to, but it appears in my dev tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I've been banging my head against the problem for embarrassingly long now. I'm using Angular UI Router to handling the routing in a small personal project I'm working on, and I have a strange issue. I have a VERY simple HTML file:

```
<head>

  <title>MY FUN EXCITING PROJECT</title>

  <script src='node_modules/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script src='node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'></script>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
  <script src='routes.js'></script>
  <script src='dist/auth/authenticationController.js'></script>
  <script src='dist/auth/authenticationFactory.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <H1>I AM A FILE. HELLO.</H1>
  <a ui-sref='login'>CLICK ME</a>

</body>
```

And, again, a VERY simple route provider file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('project',['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl:'dist/auth/authentication.html'
      });
  }])
})();
```

And the authentication.html file is literally just a

## I AM AN AUTHENTICATION PAGE

right now.

What's happening is that clicking on the link will cause the address in the address bar to change properly, but the template itself won't render. If I look in the dev tools, though, the page is being sent back from the response (screenshot attached).  [image]

I'm using a basic barebones node server to run the server for this, and using

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

to serve all the files. Is there something basic I'm missing? I'd infinitely appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: You're missing `ui-view` directive - ui-router has to have a place where it can put a template.

Comment: Where would I stick that ui-view? I actually tried writing <div ui-view><a ui-sref='login'>CLICK ME</a></div> and it just renders the template on the same page instead of routing me to it.

Comment: It should be somewhere in your `body`, see docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view

Comment: I just got it working. Thank you!